# How to increase the image size of tab bar item in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm customising my tab bar programatically by using [ESTabBarController](https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController). I want to increase the image size of the middle tab bar by using this code but not working.

```
v3.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
v3.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0)
```

this is the code in app delegate:

```
v1.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "账本", image: UIImage(named: "tab-icon-1"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tab-icon-1a"))
v2.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "账户", image: UIImage(named: "tab-icon-2"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tab-icon-2a"))
v3.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "tab-icon-3"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tab-icon-3"))
v4.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "发现", image: UIImage(named: "tab-icon-4"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tab-icon-4a"))
v5.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "我的", image: UIImage(named: "tab-icon-5"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tab-icon-5a"))

(v1.tabBarItem as? ESTabBarItem)?.contentView?.renderingMode = .automatic
(v2.tabBarItem as? ESTabBarItem)?.contentView?.renderingMode = .automatic
(v3.tabBarItem as? ESTabBarItem)?.contentView?.renderingMode = .automatic
(v4.tabBarItem as? ESTabBarItem)?.contentView?.renderingMode = .automatic
(v5.tabBarItem as? ESTabBarItem)?.contentView?.renderingMode = .automatic

tabBarController.viewControllers = [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]
```

This is stimulator screenshot, I want to increase the middle (+) tab bar item a bit.

[image]

Comment: None of your code says anything about image size

Comment: v3.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height = 4? sorry, I'm don't know how to set the image size.. @matt